Run wsl related command with gitlab runner
I am setting up a Gitlab Pipeline for my project. The gitlab runner is configured as a service on a Windows Machine. The problem comes when I try to execute any command that need the wsl. Wrapping the wsl command inside a script also does not help. I am sure that the user of gitlab runner have the necessary permission as well. Has anyone faced the same issue? Even the wsl --list command is failing for me. One strange thing I noticed is that the wsl --list does have some output (some blank line) but somehow the exit code is -1
